# SSL Certificate error for www.superuser.com (but not superuser.com)

Tags: bug, ssl

Just a note that when I tried to go to "https://www.superuser.com" (as many of us are want to type in, including the www) I get a certificate warning. I don't get the same error when I go to "https://superuser.com".

Up to you as to whether that's a problem or not, just thought you should know.

www.superuser.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net, *.sstatic.net, serverfault.com, meta.serverfault.com, superuser.com, meta.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com, *.meta.stackexchange.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Comment: `www.superuser.com` simply redirects to `superuser.com`. It's not used anywhere, and never has been AFAIK. The only way to get there is to enter the wrong URL directly.

Comment: [Www is bad!](http://no-www.org/)

Comment: How did you get to www.superuser.com instead of superuser.com?

Comment: Note: I'm running the HTTPSEverywhere add-on in Firefox, which seems to route me to https + ://www.superuser.com if I type in www.superuser.com - which does not immediately redirect me to the non www site. What can I say, I'm old and used to typing in the www ;?)

Comment: It can't redirect you before the SSL connection has been established. I'm calling this one a user error. Issues caused by HTTPS Everywhere are numerous and well known (e.g. BBC).

Comment: @DanielBeck I wouldn't call it a user *error*; it's extremely non-user-friendly for `https://www.somesite.com` to throw a cert error. A cert for *.superuser.com should exist. Yes, it's added expense, but it was SE's fault for choosing not to make everything a subdomain of *.stackexchange as it is (it's less characters to type superuser.com, sure, but also more expensive to support multiple domains). Both the [no-www](http://no-www.org) and [yes-www](http://www.yes-www.org) crowds strongly recommend that all sites support both www and naked domains; SSL is just a special case of that.

Comment: And don't blame it on HTTPS Everywhere, either; security is important; man in the middle attacks are becoming more common; and there is very strong justification for users to desire security (to prevent session hijacking, for instance). I wouldn't be surprised if browsers such as Chrome and Firefox start implementing functionality like HTTPS Everywhere into the core browser and enabled by default within the next few years.

Comment: Unless I missed something, HTTPS isn't officially deployed yet. The reason you land on a HTTPS site is that the rules in HTTPSEverywhere are broken.

Comment: In a browser address bar, Ctrl+Return adds a `.com` to the end of whatever you've typed, and `www.` to the beginning, @random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You bring up a valid point. Based on the description of your problem, I would consider this to be a bug that should be resolved by the SE team by adding a valid SSL cert, either specifically for `www.superuser.com`, *or* for `*.superuser.com`.

Account security is a very important subject, and SE has been investing lots of time and resources into getting SSL working across all their services. This is a commendable effort, but SSL is still a work in progress for them, and they have not had the time or resources to get certificates issued for every domain and subdomain. `www.superuser.com` is a valid way to access Super User, even if it's not the *preferred* way.

Both [no-www](http://no-www.org) and [yes-www](http://www.yes-www.org) -- two disagreeing camps on whether or not to use `www` in URLs -- agree on the point that every website should be accessible via both the "naked domain" (e.g. `http(s)://superuser.com`) and via its `www.` equivalent (e.g. `http(s)://www.superuser.com`).

As of now, we have the following situation:

`http://superuser.com` -- Works fine.

`http://www.superuser.com` -- Works fine, redirects to `http://superuser.com`, compliant with no-www standards.

`https://superuser.com` -- Works fine for protecting your session cookie. Some site resources are loaded over unencrypted channels, but this is only a risk for content injection; the browser security model still makes it difficult to extract the session cookie cross-domain without obtaining local user trust, which is generally not practical. So you get a security upgrade, and otherwise the site is fine.

`https://www.superuser.com` -- Broken! There is no standards justification I can find to support leaving this broken, and it's liable to scare away or discourage at least a couple users.

Comment: https isn't officially deployed, and till it's done, I wouldn't consider it as a bug

Comment: @Sathya Adding a cert for www.superuser.com should be considered part of the deployment *process* for completing the rollout of HTTPS, then. SE does things gradually and iteratively rather than just rolling out the whole thing in one finished lump; having this cert added would bring them *closer* to being "done". By the same token, they couldn't sanely call the HTTPS rollout "done" in any way until all their domains that are accessible over HTTP are also accessible over HTTPS.